# What changes were made to Unity webapps in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, webapps

The webapps feature introduced in 12.10 seemed like it had a lot of potential, but it also seemed like an early preview, with limited functionality and some bugs. Having updated to 13.04, it all looks the same. Were any new webapps introduced, or features added or improved in the existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a video demoing the new Web Apps integration in Ubuntu: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUTNxi6b-hw . There are no new things about that in 13.04.